# Global and local scope variables in Python; Delete item inside from array inside the loop

Tags: python, arrays, variables, scope

This is the code:

```
def deleteObj(array):
    for i in range (0, len(array)):
        if array[i]:
            if type(array[i]) == int or type(array[i]) == float:
                if int(array[i]) == 0:
                    del array[i]
        elif not array[i]:
            break

    print(array)
```

So, at the end it prints me whole array without changes. I've broke my mind already xDxDxD
P.S. I can't make array a global variable before posting inside function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two problems:

1. `if array[i]:` will be false when `array[i]` is `None`, but also when it is `0`.
2. You are removing from `array` while iterating on it, it will cause iterating `list index out of range`

You need to check if the item is `None` explicitly, and use `remove` on a copy of `array` so you can remove items. You can also skip the checks for `int` or `float` and the casting to `int`, they are not necessary

```
def deleteObj(array):
    for item in list(array):
        if item is not None:
            if item == 0:
                array.remove(item)
        else:
            break

    print(array)
```

Comment: Could you please help with another? Until this cooldown for questions.

Comment: I have code: array.sort(key=lambda item: item is 0) \n sorted(array, key=lambda x: (x == 0) and x is not False) \n Input list is ["a",0.0,0,"b",None,"c","d",0,1,False,0,1,0,3,[],0,1,9,0,0,{},0,0,9] \n So it returns right after first attempt but does nothing with float